# TextView inside ConstraintLayout clips text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I encountered a strange behavior of the TextView inside the ConstraintLayout.

TextView cuts the text.
On a screenshot you see three choices:

1. TextView has width="match_parent" - correct bounds, but text is clipped;
2. TextView has width="wrap_content" - incorrect bounds and text is clipped again;
3. TextView inside LinearLayout - this is an example of how it should have been.

[image]

ConstraintLayout, what's wrong with you?

---

Here is my XML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#727272"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/block"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/block" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/block"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/block2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/block2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/block2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/block2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is `ConstraintLayout` version ?

Comment: @Ironman 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alph‌​a4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's known bug and as Google promised

> Released in alpha 5

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215537